# Derived Attribute both in Where Clause and Order By

Tags: sql, jpa

I am returning a complex derived attribute in my SQL statement called "FULLNAME"  e.g.

```
select p.id,
       nvl2(p.ID, upper(p.ATTR1) || ... decode(..) + ) as fullname, // details omitted
       // ...
from 
    person_t p, ...
where
    lower(fullname) like '%abc%' 
order by
    fullname asc;
```

Previously we were using Hibernate which allows you to attach a `@Formula` annotation for derived attributes; then you can use the custom field in HQL.

But now we have to transition to JPA, and I have to remove all Hibernate-specific stuff. This requires a rewrite into regular SQL.

The custom field doesn't work in the (1) Where Clause and in the (2) Order By in plain SQL. Is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

The use of aliases in `where` in not allowed in most of the db. instead in order by is normally allowed.

So you should repeat the code (related to the alias)  in where

eg :

```
select p.id,
     nvl2(p.ID, upper(p.ATTR1) || ... decode(..) + ) as fullname, // details omitted
               // ...
from  person_t p, ...
where  lower( nvl2(p.ID, upper(p.ATTR1) || ... decode(..) + ) ) like '%abc%' 
order by  fullname asc;
```